# elasticsearch node client using mget on index alias bringing back docs not in alias

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am using the node js client for ES.

I am doing an mget but using alias for index field and not an actual index. 
It works in the sense it brings back results but one of the documents is not in the alias but in the underlying index i.e. it should fail the alias test and so not come come back in the result but it is.

```
itemIds = ['3504479-4-41','3504700-4-41'];//test, second id is not in alias
esClient.mget({
     index: 'live_articles',
     _source: ['id','itemTypeId','headline','itemUrl','startDate','summary', 'onlineStatus'],
            body: {ids: itemIds}
        }, function (err, resp) {
            var items = [];
            console.log(resp.docs);
        });
```

does mget in this usage instance ignore the conditions of the alias and just use the alias to get the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you are hitting this issue: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/3861.

An alias can hold a filter, which will be used to filter the search results, like a default filter. The tricky part is when you use the get api (or multi_get), as it implies real-time and not executing a search but only get by id, which can be done against the transaction log too if the document is not yet available for search in the lucene index (in case a refresh has not happened yet). That means that in that case the filter will be ignored, as using a filter would imply executing a search, which would cause you to lose the real-timeness of get apis.